# how to return a generic type in java axis webservice

Tags: web-services, axis

I want to return a MyObject type of object in a webservice

however, the service seems to be refusing to be rebuilt after i convert the method into such an object
how can i do that with this service?

EDIT:

my webservice refuses to work if the response object is built like this:

```
public class MyObject {


public MyObject(){
initializesomehow
}

}


public class ServerData T {

public T data;

}


public class ServerResponse{

public ServerData<MyObject> sendResponse{
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
ServerData<MyObject> data = new ServerData<MyObject>();
return data;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the before code that builds, and the after code that doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience，generic type is not supported in axis2, the generated wsdl file will not recognize the MyOBject and will set type to AnyType, then the client will get a "Any type element type has not been given" error.

Comment: actually i figured out a workaround - > you simply need to create a mapping in the wsdl for each object, and it is done by creating a method for each object, that simply returns an empty object, unfortunately those methods must be public...